# Oracle 12c - complicated update and delete

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle12c, sql-delete

I have the following scenario in a auditing table (AUDIT_TABLE).

```
t_id  e_id     detail_log                                                    date_created
01    111      USER_1; Salary: from '25' to '30'; Dept_ID: from '001' to ''; 01/01/2019 
02    111      USER_1; Dept_ID: from '' to '001';                            01/01/2019
03    001      USER_1; Dept_ID: from '012' to '';                            01/01/2019
04    002      USER_1; Dept_ID: from '555' to '666';                         01/01/2019
05    222      USER_1; Dept_ID: from '' to '123';                            01/02/2019
06    333      USER_1; Salary: from '10' to '20'; Dept_ID: from '200' to ''; 01/03/2019
07    444      USER_1; Salary: from '50' to '100'; Dept_ID: from '' to '10'; 01/04/2019
```

There's a bug in the batch processes that trigger inserts into this audit table and creates these records "`Dept_ID: from .. to`" when there is no change in the "`Dept_ID`" value (in another table). There are millions of these records that need to be cleaned up. The records that have multiple field changes captured i.e. `item_id 01` needs to be updated to clear the `Dept_ID`: audit message and the records that have only the `Dept_ID` audit record needs to be deleted (`item_id 02`). There may be other pairs that have only the `Dept ID` audit message in both the records, in which case both need to be deleted. The trigger logic has been fix so no more false records are being created when there is no actual change in the `Dept ID`, however the records already created during the bug need to be cleaned up. There may be rows where there is only one record of the pair in which case these do not need to be updated/deleted because the Dept_ID was actually changed to a null or changed from a null to a value.

So the following should exist after fixing the above data-set:

```
t_id  e_id     detail_log                                                    date_created
01    111      USER_1; Salary: from '25' to '30';                            01/01/2019 
03    001      USER_1; Dept_ID: from '012' to '';                            01/01/2019
04    002      USER_1; Dept_ID: from '555' to '666';                         01/01/2019
05    222      USER_1; Dept_ID: from '' to '123';                            01/02/2019
06    333      USER_1; Salary: from '10' to '20'; Dept_ID: from '200' to ''; 01/03/2019
07    444      USER_1; Salary: from '50' to '100'; Dept_ID: from '' to '10'; 01/04/2019
```

I have delete and update statements ready to do this but if I delete one record of the pair, then the update won't find the other record since it depends on the deleted record to find it and vice versa for the update statement. I thought to use the merge statement but not sure how to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming such test data

```
DETAIL_LOG                                                                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USER_1; Salary: from '25' to '30'; Dept_ID: from '001' to '';                             
USER_1; Dept_ID: from '' to '001';                                                        
USER_1; Salary: from '25' to '30'; Dept_ID: from '001' to '002'; Prdeel: from '0' to '1': 
USER_1; Dept_ID: from '' to '';
```

if I get you right, you want to remove the `Dept_ID` entry from the first and second row because one of the values is NULL. I added forth row with  both NULL value which should be removed as well.

The third row remain unchanged, because both value are filled.

You need this regexp to replace the data

```
 q'[(Dept_ID: from '.*' to '';|Dept_ID: from '' to '.*';)]'
```

Note that the bar in the middle represents OR. The left part matches the departments with `to` value NULL, the rigth part the department with `from` value NULL.

The matched string is replaced with a NULL string.

To limit the scope of updated records the exact logik of the buggy records must be defined. Here an example where I expect that both records must have the same `e_id` and are ordered on `t_id`

Using `LEAD` and `LAG` you examines the following and preceeding recods to check if the condition of the *change to emtpy* and *change from empty* is fullfilled.

Note that I'm using `LIKE` to filter the rows to get better performance.

Query to final check before the update:)

```
with al as (
select T_ID, E_ID, DETAIL_LOG, 
lead(DETAIL_LOG) over (partition by e_id  order by t_id) DETAIL_LOG_LEAD,
lag(DETAIL_LOG) over (partition by e_id  order by t_id) DETAIL_LOG_LAG
from AUDIT_TABLE)
select T_ID, E_ID,
/* updated entry */
regexp_replace(detail_log, q'[(Dept_ID: from '.*' to '';|Dept_ID: from '' to '.*';)]', '') DETAIL_LOG
from al
where (DETAIL_LOG      like q'[%Dept_ID: from '_%' to '';%]' and /* first wrong record */
       DETAIL_LOG_LEAD like q'[%Dept_ID: from '' to '_%';%]') OR
      (DETAIL_LOG      like q'[%Dept_ID: from '' to '_%';%]' and /* second wrong record */
       DETAIL_LOG_LAG  like q'[%Dept_ID: from '_%' to '';%]') 
;
```

returns

```
      T_ID       E_ID DETAIL_LOG                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
---------- ---------- ------------
         1        111 USER_1; Salary: from '25' to '30';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
         2        111 USER_1;
```

**Update**

The `UPDATE` statement is a simple reformulation of the query above using `IN` (subquery) to limit the scope.

```
update AUDIT_TABLE
set DETAIL_LOG = regexp_replace(detail_log, q'[(Dept_ID: from '.*' to '';|Dept_ID: from '' to '.*';)]', '')
where (T_ID, E_ID) in 
-- query from above that limits the updated rows
```

To delete the *empty* audit records after this cleanup is a trivial step.

Comment: This would work IF I didn't have valid records when the Dept ID actually changed to a NULL or from a NULL to a NOT NULL. I don't want to touch those records which weren't affected from this bug, the ones that don't have a pair, going from a not null to a null and immediately after another record for going from null to a not null.

Comment: Well you'll have to somehow more carefully explain how do you *pair* the records to be deleted. E.g. both records must have the same `e_id` and are ordered on `t_id`.  Without this information only *IF* (i.e speculative) answers are possible....

Comment: t_id will be sequential in the pair, and e_id will be same, however there may be other audit records for same e_id.

Comment: well check the updated answer, should be the exact solution now.

Comment: hats off to you.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the rows those should remain have a data of `Salary:` with adjacent colon at the end like in your case, then consider deleting the rows without `Salary:` ;

```
delete audit_table where instr(detail_log,'Salary:') = 0;
```

and then updating the `detail_log` column's data by trimming the rest after `Dept_ID:` string

```
update audit_table 
   set detail_log = regexp_replace(detail_log, '(.*)Dept_ID:.*', '\1');
```

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/TEQWZ53623)</kbd>

Comment: @user3224907 please share those cases as added to already given two rows to make us understand what you mean.

Comment: Please see my description now. Added the data as well.